# Principled BDSF shader is not showing up in shader list in node editor

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

Principled BDSF not showing up in my 2.8, when I go into node editor to start a node tree.

Comment: Didn't you select the world settings instead of the object? A little Earth icon near a little yellow box.

Answer (score 1):

As there's not a 2.89, I'll assume you're talking about 2.79.

Check that you're on Cycles mode, and not Blender Internal. You can find it on the upper menu.